Autoplay Audio HTMl
I am Trying to Create an auto play audio to play in website background
I am creating a web application for music and I decided to test it with an autoplay audio first to see how it goes.
<audio src="01-NF-HOPE-(JustNaija.com).mp3" loop autoplay></audio>

this code worked on my local computer but when I Hosted it, it didn't play in the background

check this SO question link. It seems that user interaction is needed and no autoplay is possible
